# pass model from one action to another action in same controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, asp.net-4.0, asp.net-mvc-3-areas

I am trying to pass my model **List< Models.Statement > statementList** from one action to another but i am receiving null value in the 2nd controller. Please suggest what is wrong here. Even tried with:

```
return RedirectToAction("WriteInTemplate", new { statementList = statementList });
```

Please help.

```
    public ActionResult SendPdfStatement(string InvoiceNumber)
    {
        try
        {
            InvoiceNumber = InvoiceNumber.Trim();

            ObjectParameter[] parameters = new ObjectParameter[1];
            parameters[0] = new ObjectParameter("InvoiceNumber", InvoiceNumber);

            List<Models.Statement> statementList = new List<Models.Statement>();
            statementList = _db.ExecuteFunction<Models.Statement>("uspInvoiceStatement", parameters).ToList<Models.Statement>();

            //WriteInTemplate(statementList);
            return RedirectToAction("WriteInTemplate", statementList );

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            InvoiceSearchTool.Models.udtExceptionTable exception = new udtExceptionTable();
            exception.MethodName = "SendPdfStatement";
            exception.Exception = e.ToString();
            exception.Date = DateTime.Now;
            DYNAMICS_EXTEntities db = new DYNAMICS_EXTEntities();
            db.AddToudtExceptionTables(exception);
            db.SaveChanges();  
            return View("Error");
        }
    }

    public ActionResult WriteInTemplate(List<Models.Statement> statementList)
    {
        try
        {
            string invoiceNumber = statementList.FirstOrDefault().Invoice.ToString().Trim();
        ...................snip..........


            return RedirectToAction("CreateMessageWithAttachment", "email", invoiceNumber); 
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            InvoiceSearchTool.Models.udtExceptionTable exception = new udtExceptionTable();
            exception.MethodName = "WriteInTemplate";
            exception.Exception = e.ToString();
            exception.Date = DateTime.Now;
            DYNAMICS_EXTEntities db = new DYNAMICS_EXTEntities();
            db.AddToudtExceptionTables(exception);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return View("Error");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Why not do return WriteInTemplate(statementList); instead? You should probably move the common functionality in another method.

Comment: @amit_g is correct.  just "return WriteInTemplate(statementList);"  That is also an ActionResult so it will work as desired.

Answer (score 3):

Please take a look  [here to pass your Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18963704/passing-model-through-redirectaction-is-null#18963758)

you are not passing "statementList" , instead you are passing new { statementList= statementList} just pass the model and you should be fine .

```
return RedirectToAction("WriteInTemplate", statementList);
```

Answer by sino

Answer (score 1):

`RedirectToAction()` writes a redirect command to the browser, making it start a brand new request to `WriteInTemplate()`. Your model object is therefore lost.

Is `WriteInTemplate()` an independent action which will sometimes be responsible for an entire request from a user or a partial request from a view? If not, you should just call it as a regular method instead of using `RedirectToAction()`.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you had spefified wrong route parameters.

while thinking about this.. did you check that the data are not null?

you are using

```
 return RedirectToAction("WriteInTemplate", statementList );
```

instead you should use

```
return RedirectToAction("WriteInTemplate","controllerName", new{"statementList"=stetementList});
```

see reference [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction%28v=vs.98%29.aspx)

Comment: He said he was in the same controller, therefore what he has would have worked and is using correct parameters.

Answer (score 1):

The way you call the RedirectToAction() method may not be your issue.

For me, the solutions presented above did not work because the RedirectToAction() method builds a RouteValueDictionary by using the .ToString() value of each property in the model.  **This will only work if all the properties in the model are simple properties and it fails if any properties are complex objects, lists, collections, etc.**
 because this method does not use recursion.

If for example, a model called MymodelOrganization contained a property List Employees, then that property would result in a query string value of
....&Employees=System.Collections.Generic.List'1[System.String]
and binding would fail,  and you would end up (as was my case) with  ...   null

I had this problem, so I created a copy of my model containing only the elements of the form, stripping my Lists and passed that inside RedirectToAction(). 
Once on the other action method, I was able to re-assemble my Lists and added them to my Model before calling the last return.  Good luck.    Here is the idea in my code:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ItemSubmissionForm(CombinedModelContent membervalues)
{ ...
    ItemSubmissionsDBFields aFieldsList = membervalues.FieldsList;  //Stripping other objects
    return RedirectToAction("ItemSubmissionConfirm", aFieldsList);
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ItemSubmissionConfirm(ItemSubmissionsDBFields aFieldsList)
{ ...
   List<SomeArea> SomeAreaitems = new List<SomeArea>();
   SomeAreaitems.Add  ...

   CombinedModelContent copymembervalues = new CombinedModelContent();
        copymembervalues.SomeCodeLists = SomeAreaitems;
        copymembervalues.FieldsList = aFieldsList;  
   return View("SomeConfirmPage", copymembervalues);
```