# Passing Model through RedirectAction is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, parameter-passing

- In My main controller to switch views I just call another Action from my controller, but my model I am passing is null after being passed, and is not null beforehand.

  ```
  public ActionResult Index(ViewModelViewImages model)
  {
      return RedirectToAction("ViewImages", new { passedModel = model });
  }
  ```
- In the same Controller..

  ```
  public ActionResult ViewImages(ViewModelViewImages passedModel)
  {
      //passedModel.(WhateverMyAttributesAre) = null every time
  }
  ```

---

- However I can write out my variables and they pass just fine

  ```
      string pro = model.Prospects;
      string cnt = model.Countys;
      string twn = model.TownShips;
      string rng = model.Ranges;
      string sct = model.Sections;

      return RedirectToAction("ViewImages", new { idpro = pro , idcnt = cnt, idtwn = twn, idrng = rng, idsct = sct});
  ```
- In Return I'd receive them in the other Action like so

  ```
      public ActionResult ViewImages(string idpro, string idcnt, string idtwn, string idrng, string idsct)
  ```

*I've been looking for couple hours now only came across [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9024693/pass-model-from-one-action-to-another-action-in-same-controller)  that doesn't have a specific answer yet either.*

**There a good reason for this? / What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are not passing "`ViewModelViewImages`" , instead you are passing `new { passedModel = model }`
just pass the model and you should be fine .

```
public ActionResult Index(ViewModelViewImages model)
{
    return RedirectToAction("ViewImages",   model  );
}
```

Comment: Wow , ill accept the answer in 10 when I am allowed. Thanks for the quick answer.